# Set colorbox in .load-callback in Facebook Tab/Canvas

Tags: facebook, callback, colorbox

I'm having a little issue with the colorbox when using it in a facebook tab/canvas.

Basically I load another file (that contains a few images) with ajax (jQuery) into my canvas page and I want to let colorbox open those pictures. It all works fine when I attach the colorbox in the callback of my ajax `.load` *as long as I'm **not** in the facebook canvas*.

But as soon as I open the page in facebook, it won't open colorbox anymore. All other jQuery functions are working though.

Code-Example

```
$('#slider').load('content.php', { ajax: 'on' }, function(e) {
            $('.gallery').colorbox({rel:'gal'});
});
```

I found a solution to make it work - I need to define the colorbox in the file that is getting loaded with ajax. But I don't understand why it's not working in the callback and I don't think it's a very nice solution. Before I want to move on and develop further things in my fb-canvas, I need to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a few quick and dirty test now and it all works fine. I tried reproducing the problem, but couldn't find anything. I must have been blind, but my debugger actually complained about the callback of the .load()! It was just one line (before the colorbox-call):

```
$('#slider').css({left: (-100 * $('#' + History.getState().data['show']).position().left / $('#data').width()) + '%'});
```

I can't see any problems with it and I'm no expert, but my debugger (Firebug) had no reason for listing it in the console either (without any comment) as it still worked - except from the colorbox-call after it. And here's the thing: After putting the colorbox-call in front of this line (it's all in the same callback of the `load()`), it all worked.

Still confused and don't know what this was.
I'm still not sure whether this is now unrelated to colorbox or not, because there debugger only cries when I put the colorbox-call right behind it. Weird!